# Why would our Java app not display windows on secondary monitor?

Tags: java, swing, windows-vista

We have a Java/Swing client that's been around for quite a few years. When I moved from XP to Vista (client ONLY runs on Windows), I noticed that whenever a new window is created (usually a JFrame descendant) on my secondary monitor, the window initially shows as blank, i.e. instead of showing the normal contents of the window, it's just a solid block of gray. If I then drag that window onto the primary monitor, the second it crosses the monitor boundary, it draws itself properly and I can drag it back to the secondary monitor.  If the window is created on the primary monitor, it always comes into existence perfectly.  I NEVER had this problem on XP, only on Vista. I'm unable to easily test it on Windows 7, lacking a dual monitor Windows 7 machine.

Anybody have *any* ideas? Is this perhaps a known Java bug? I'm also running the most recent Java 1.6 SDK.

Comment: Check if the Java client actually is told to repaint.

Comment: You could try playing around with the GraphicsEnvironment class.  This allows you to get a list of all monitors connected to the computer.

Comment: I had a similar problem in my game where if I were to drag the window to my secondary monitor, it would go white until I drag it back. After dragging it back the screen doesn't update anymore.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check that the video driver and the ***JRE*** are up to date. (It is possible to have a current JDK, but an old JRE.)

Java will delegate the buffering to DirectDraw and/or Direct3D. You can disable this with the following JVM options:

- `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false`
- `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true`

There are other options detailed [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html).

If the primary monitor is to the right of the secondary monitor, the screen positions on the secondary monitor will have negative X values. (Likewise if the secondary is above the primary positions will have negative Y values.) It is possible there is code that is not handling the negative values.

Comment: I updated the video driver and checked the JRE. No change. I added the two JVM options mentioned and the problem went away. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Awesome.  This also worked for me for a third party Java client on Win10.