# Force System Properties in a JAR

Tags: java, swing, jar

I currently had a problem similar to this previous question:

[Why would our Java app not display windows on secondary monitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602590/why-would-our-java-app-not-display-windows-on-secondary-monitor)

The answer was to include:

- Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
- Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true

So I created my shortcut to launch the application as such:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\javaw.exe -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false  -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -jar <file name>
```

Is there anyway to force that application to use that in code and not have to use parameters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`System.setProperty(property, value);`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) at the beginning of your program. Eg:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.d3d", "false");
    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true");

    // Start your real application
}
```

Comment: The exact code for me that worked was

    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.d3d", "false");
    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true");

Comment: Halfwarr: Oh, ok. Hadn't expected it.

Answer (score 1):

`System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true");` alone was enough to do it.

We had been seeing massive screen tearing (or artifacts getting drawn) in our Java application with more new, powerful computers (e.g. with NVidia GTX 3090 card etc.), but not with all DirectX 12 setups.

The common way to get this issue to materialize was that when we displayed tooltip popups or when a menu-panel went outside the client frame (or canvas), screen tearing of sorts started happening. Basically, the whole application screen was getting then drawn, starting at the point of action (for example, at the point of blinking cursor or a graphical element that you moved your mouse over).

We had during trying to fix this, implemented in multiple locations those revalidate(); and repaint(); functions, but there were still plenty of ways it was breaking. However, the above solved our issue once and for all.

Comment: This is an eleven year old question.