# How to programatically disable 3D acceleration on a java application?

Tags: java, swing, awt

With the latest update to Java 8, my MineSweeper game that I made using Java swing and awt, now visually lags an extreme amount.
(When I hit a mine, now I can see each mine populate one by one, where before they seemed to appear at the same time.)
I just have the game in a jar file. If I use a bat file to open the game, I can set:
-Dsun.java2d.accthreshold=0 -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true (-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false is the main one. Not sure if the other are needed or even make a difference...)
This speeds up the game to run like before, but now has the command prompt in the background, and can't find the folder where the scores are stored.
If I use a Windows shortcut to the jar file, I can't figure out how to set those properties, but it runs without the command prompt in the background and can find the scores folder.

What I was hoping to do was add System.setProperty() calls in the java class to get it to work, but no avail:

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.d3d", "false");
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.ddoffscreen", "false");
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true");
```

This seems to set the properties, but yields none of the results that the bat file does.

Edit: Oddly, calling System.setProperty("sun.java2d.accthreshold", "0"); in Main with all the rest of them prints: New Default Acceleration Threshold: 0 to the console.

How can I set them so that this game can run correctly on any machine?

Comment: Have you tried to put those three lines are the beginning of the `main` method?

Comment: Yes. That is where they are. I can even use System.getProperty() on all of them, and that shows that they have been set, but the visuals are still slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217243/force-system-properties-in-a-jar)

What I was doing wrong (Sorry for not specifying in my question), was I had no main method. I pointed to the constructor of the game object as the main method, and that's where I was trying to set the properties and also create the display components and render them.
By creating a standard main method and setting the properties in it, then calling the constructor of the game object, I was able to get it to run fast again.